# How to add the values of two OrderedDict objects in python, keeping the order?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I would like to add two `OrderedDict` objects like these:

```
dict1 = OrderedDict([('Table', [10, 20, 30, 'wood']), ('Chair', [200, 300, 400, 'wood'])])
dict2 = OrderedDict([('Table', ['red', 55]), ('Chair', ['blue', 200])])
```

And create a new  `OrderedDict` like this (the order is important):

```
dict3 = OrderedDict([('Table', [10, 20, 30, 'wood', 'red', 55]), ('Chair', [200, 300, 400, 'wood', 'blue', 200])])
```

If there are any keys in `dict1` or `dict2` that are not present in the other, those should be ignored, only matching keys should be used for the output. All values are lists.

Comment: And you want to have a **new** dictionary as output, right? Not updating the lists in `dict1` or `dict2`.

Comment: Actually, updating any of the dicts would work as well.

Comment: I've cleaned up your question and added one more assumption: that all values are lists.

Comment: Another edge-case: what should happen if the *order* in `dict2` differs from the order of `dict1`?

Answer (score 5):

Because you want to preserve the order of your `OrderedDict` objects, you need to loop over one and test each key against the other to produce the union of the two key sets:

```
dict3 = OrderedDict((k, dict1[k] + dict2[k]) for k in dict1 if k in dict2)
```

Looping over `dict1` ensures that we output keys for the new dictionary in the same order, testing with `k in dict2` ensures we only use keys that are present in *both* input mappings.

You can also update `dict1` in-place with `list.extend()`:

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
    if key in dict2:
        value.extend(dict2[key])
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dict1 = OrderedDict([('Table', [10, 20, 30, 'wood']), ('Chair', [200, 300, 400, 'wood'])])
>>> dict2 = OrderedDict([('Table', ['red', 55]), ('Chair', ['blue', 200])])
>>> OrderedDict((k, dict1[k] + dict2[k]) for k in dict1 if k in dict2)
OrderedDict([('Table', [10, 20, 30, 'wood', 'red', 55]), ('Chair', [200, 300, 400, 'wood', 'blue', 200])])
```

Comment: That worked exactly as I needed! Thanks a lot Martijn!

Comment: @Martijn Pieters how can you generalize the first solution to add N OrderedDict(()?

Comment: @azal: there is no shortcut, just repeat the operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict3 = {}
for i in dict1:
    if i in dict2:
        dict3[i]=[]
        for j in dict1[i]:
            dict3[i].append(j)
        for j in dict2[i]:
            dict3[i].append(j)
```

Comment: Note that since you are just using a dict, the ordering isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Since it is iterating over elements of `dict1` first and then over `dict2`, I think all the values of a particular key will be in order. Let me know if I am wrong in thinking so. :)

Comment: It depends how you interpret "keeping the order".  From the fact that the original code was using OrderedDicts, I think the requirement was for keys and values to be ordered.